# Are trade deficits good/bad or neither?

Tags: international-trade

Is there an academic consensus on whether a trade deficit is good/bad or neither?

And if that country is in a monetary union, does the answer change because the wealth moved out of the country can be utilised elsewhere (whereas, for example, a pound can only be used as legal tender in the UK)?